# Using MPlayer in Qt5

Tags: c++, linux, video, qt5, qtmultimedia

I have a problem with default QtMultimedia backend GStreamer on my BeagleBone Black machine. When I am playing video over GStreamer it has a lot frame drops, and video is very slow. Behavior is the same when I play video over gstreamer command **gst-launch-1.0 /home/debian/Desktop/video.mp4** .

Its not the case with MPlayer and video playback, everything works perfect, so I would like to use MPlayer instead of GStreamer in my Qt application for video playback, where to start with this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: 'apt-get install mplayer'... i really never used mplayer for video, but for audio it's quite simple, and i guess it should follow the logic... to play audio with mplayer, use this:

## mplayer -ao alsa -volume <'volumeInt'> <'file'>

Where:

<'volumeInt'> - values between 0 - 100;

<'arquivo'> - Target file.

To run in background, add the parameters (without simple quotes on
   path): <'/dev/null' >/dev/null 2>&1 &